# Google Cloud ML Engine: Keras model prediction includes name of last layer

Tags: keras, google-cloud-ml

I have a keras model with tensorflow backend hosted on ML Engine.  I ping it for a prediction with:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model my_model --version my_version --json-instances my_instances.json
```

and I get back:

`MY_SECOND_DENSE
[0.0003, 0.2819, ...]`

`my_second_dense` is the name of the output layer in my keras model.  Do we know why the name of my model's output layer is included in the prediction result?  Is there a way to avoid this?

More to the point, what is the data type of the response here?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
def get_model(model):
    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
    def serving():
        inputs = {
            'reviews': tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 100], dtype='float32')
        }
        preproc = inputs.copy()
        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(preproc, inputs)

    estimator.export_savedmodel('./test_export', serving)
```

Comment: Can you include some info about how the model was exported to a SavedModel? Usually you configure the outouts at export time.

Comment: @rhaertel80 Sure thing, just edited my post.  It's pretty boilerplate afaik

Comment: The results of prediction should be something like this: `{"predictions": [{"name_of_output": [0.0, 0.1, ...]}]}` Can you confirm the output of `gcloud` looks that way Is your question about the name of the key inside the map? Or the values inside the list, or what?

Comment: My question is more about what the response type is for running `gcloud ml-engine predict ...` and why it includes `MY_SECOND_DENSE` instead of just the array of probabilities?  Values inside the list are as expected

Comment: The service itself should be returning a JSON response similar to my previous comment. It may be that gcloud is converting the output to some table. Try adding `--format=JSON` or `--format=json` to see the actual output? Anyways, I *think* the answer to your question is that TensorFlow/Keras models are expressive enough to allow for multiple outputs, so the response JSON has to include a dict mapping the name of each output to its values; in your case, there is only one output so it's not strictly necessary. We could consider a feature where one could optionally surpress the output key.

Comment: @rhaertel80 thanks for the help!  I just added `--format=json` and I get: `{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "my_second_dense": [
        0.19349965453147888,
        0.010076513513922691,
        0.011453947052359581,
        0.06314714252948761,
        0.01214473508298397,
        0.015369882807135582,
        0.0562828853726387,
        0.01752925105392933,
        0.07522214204072952,
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}` So it looks like `my_second_dense` (name of last layer) is actually the key in the dict that `predictions` points to?